# how to define multiple request example for one Request Object in swagger in C#?

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

For requests, in the Swagger 2.0 spec there is only one schema for each request object defined across all the API endpoints. So if i would give same request object in multiple API endpoints, i.e. on multiple controller actions like this:

```
DeliveryOptions.cs
[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(DeliveryOptionsSearchModel), typeof(DeliveryOptionsSearchModelExample1))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeliveryOptionsForAddress(DeliveryOptionsSearchModel search)
...    

// maybe in some other controller, e.g. Search.cs
[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(DeliveryOptionsSearchModel), typeof(DeliveryOptionsSearchModelExample2))]        
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Search(DeliveryOptionsSearchModel search)


// for Example 
public class DeliveryOptionsSearchModel
{
  public string name {get; set;}
}

public class DeliveryOptionsSearchModelExample1 : Swashbuckle.Examples.IExamplesProvider 
{
    public object GetExamples()
    {
        return new DeliveryOptionsSearchModel
        {
            name= "abc"
        };
    }
}

public class DeliveryOptionsSearchModelExample2 : Swashbuckle.Examples.IExamplesProvider 
{
    public object GetExamples()
    {
        return new DeliveryOptionsSearchModel
        {
            name= "xyz"
        };
    }
}
```

That `DeliveryOptionsSearchModel` object is only defined once in the entire Swagger document.

How to define multiple request example for one Request Object(`DeliveryOptionsSearchModel`) in swagger in C# asp .net?

The problem is it's not rendering two different examples for `DeliveryOptionsSearchModel` object in swagger. Swagger UI is showing only one example Class(for example - `DeliveryOptionsSearchModelExample2` ) for All API Endpoints.

Any other ways to solve this?

[I am using the following packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlGog.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can define multiple schemes per request as follows:

```
    ///<remarks>
    /// First Schema:
    ///
    ///     GET /Todo
    ///     {
    ///         "flatId": "62a05ac8-f131-44c1-8e48-f23744289e55",
    ///         "name": "Name",
    ///         "surname": "Surname",
    ///         "personalCode": "12345",
    ///         "dateOfBirth": "2020-03-30T00:00:00",
    ///         "phoneNumber": "+37122345678",
    ///         "email": "email@mail.com"
    ///     }
    ///
    /// Second Schema:
    ///
    ///     GET /Todo
    ///     {
    ///         "name": "Name",
    ///         "surname": "Surname",
    ///         "personalCode": "12345",
    ///         "dateOfBirth": "2020-03-30T00:00:00",
    ///         "phoneNumber": "+37122345678",
    ///         "email": "email@mail.com"
    ///     }
    ///
    /// </remarks>
```

You get this result:

[Image of two schemas for requisition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrMyv.png)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="https://c2n.me/46JxgoT"><img src="https://c2n.me/46JxgoT.png" alt="Swagger UI - Google Chrome"/></a>
```

I had the same question, I sort it this way. I tried to do it through the `CreateSomethinkExample : IExampleProvider<CreateSomethink>`
but seems Swagger core doe's not supporting multiple request examples.

I sorted this problem this way, look at the `///Doc`

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Resident creation endpoint. Creating new Resident in DB and returns created item
    /// </summary>
    /// <response code="201">Success-full creation returns created item</response>
    /// <response code="400">Failed creation returns status and list of errors</response>
    /// <response code="404">House or Flat not found</response>
    /// <response code="500">Server error</response>
    /// /// <remarks>
    /// Sample request:
    ///
    ///     POST /Todo
    ///     {
    ///         "flatId": "62a05ac8-f131-44c1-8e48-f23744289e55",
    ///         "name": "Name",
    ///         "surname": "Surname",
    ///         "personalCode": "12345",
    ///         "dateOfBirth": "2020-03-30T00:00:00",
    ///         "phoneNumber": "+37122345678",
    ///         "email": "email@mail.com"
    ///     }
    ///
    ///     POST /Todo
    ///     {
    ///         "name": "Name",
    ///         "surname": "Surname",
    ///         "personalCode": "12345",
    ///         "dateOfBirth": "2020-03-30T00:00:00",
    ///         "phoneNumber": "+37122345678",
    ///         "email": "email@mail.com"
    ///     }
    ///
    /// </remarks>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(SuccessResidentCreationResponse), 201)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(FailedResidentCreationResponse), 400)]
    [HttpPost(ApiRoutes.ResidentRoute.ResidentV1)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateFlat([FromServices] Iconfiguration configuration, [FromBody] CreateResidentRequest request)
    {
        //Some logic
    }
```